# Is the branching locus of the double cover of surfaces always one dimensional?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two smooth surfaces (over the complex numbers), and $f: X \to Y$ is a finite flat morphism of degree two. Is it necessarily true that the locus where $f$ is not a smooth morphism (i.e. the ramification locus) always one dimensional (if not empty)?

Comment: Yes. The result which is true under more general conditions, is called "purity of the branch locus". I don't have access to my books
right now, otherwise I'd give you a reference.

Comment: yes, in this casethe locus is defined by one equation, the determinant.

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are smooth surfaces (this works for smooth varieties of the same dimension), the locus where $f$ is not a smooth morphism is given by the vanishing of the Jacobian determinant (as said by Roy), say, written in local coordinates. 

Purity of the branch locus (Nagata; see, eg, Grothendieck's SGA 2, X, 3.4), is more general, because it extends to schemes (if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a quasi-finite morphism of integral schemes, $X$ normal and $Y$ regular, and if $f$ is unramified outside a 2-codimensional subset, then $f$ is étale) and does not assume that $X$ is itself regular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Otherwise there would be an isolated ramification point in $Y$. A link of that point is $S^3$, which does not have a nontrivial double cover. So upstairs, $X$ looks near that point like two ${\mathbb C}^2$s glued at a point, which isn't smooth.

Comment: I feel a little silly writing this topological answer, given the beautiful algebraic geometry answers above, but I'll add: note how things are different if $Y$ were codim $1$, since the link would now be $S^1$, which does indeed have a nontrivial double cover.